# How can I debug gstreamer with gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb, gstreamer

I create gst pipeline whith c code. Now, I want the debug info of gstreamer with GDB. How can I get the error or warning info from the pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

To run gdb against your program, simply use :

```
gdb --args your_program and its args
```

If you want to break on the g_warnings and g_criticals, simply run gdb this way:

```
G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings gdb --args your_program and its args
```

The GLib will then emit SIGTRAP, allowing you to see the stack when the warning / critical was emitted.

You can also use fatal-criticals if you only want SIGTRAP  to be sent on critical errors.

Cheers!